# C++ linked list append and delete after

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I created a code that asks user for two lists, and then appends second list to the first one, it gets appended after the position of user inputted number on the first list, example:

```
First list:
1
2
3
4
5
Second list:
11
22
33
44
55
Position after which to be appended: 2
1
2
11
22
33
44
55
3
4
5
```

The problem I'm getting is that when I delete these lists, it tries to delete the same element twice, giving this execution ?code? - (0xC0000374).
I added debugging test with cout, and realized that the element that is getting deleted twice is the first element of the second list.

My code:

```
struct elem
{
    int num;
    elem *next;
};

void add_element (elem*&first1, elem*&last1, int i)
{
    elem *p = new elem;
    p->num = i;
    p->next = NULL;
    if (first1 == NULL) first1 = p;
    else last1->next = p;
    last1 = p;
};

void print_list (elem *first1)
{
    for (elem *p = first1; p!=NULL; p=p->next)
    {
        cout << p->num << endl;
    };
}

void delete_list (elem*&first1)
{
    elem* p = first1;
    while (p != NULL) {
        first1 = first1->next;
        p->next = NULL;
        cout << "Deleting element at address " << p << endl;
        delete p;
        p = first1;
    }
}

void insert_list(elem*& first1, elem*& last1, elem* p, elem* first2, elem* last2) {
    // Update the next pointer of the last element of the second list to point to NULL
    last2->next = NULL;

    if (p == NULL) { // Insert at the beginning of the list
        if (first1 == NULL) {
            first1 = first2;
        } else {
            last2->next = first1;
            first1 = first2;
        }
        if (last1 == NULL) {
            last1 = last2;
        } else {
            last1 = last2;
            // Update the last1 pointer to point to the last element in the second list
            while (last1->next != NULL) {
                last1 = last1->next;
            }
        }
    } else if (p == last1) { // Insert at the end of the list
        last1->next = first2;
        last1 = last2;
    } else { // Insert in the middle of the list
        last2->next = p->next;
        p->next = first2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    elem *first1=NULL, *last1=NULL, *p;
    int i;
    cout << "Enter the values of elements (end input with '0'): " << endl;
    cin >> i;
    while (i != 0)
    {
        add_element (first1, last1, i);
        cin >> i;
    };

    cout << "\nThe list: " << endl;
    print_list (first1);

    elem* first2 = NULL;
    elem* last2 = NULL;
    cout << "\nEnter the values of elements for the second list (end input with '0'): " << endl;
    cin >> i;
    while (i != 0) {
        add_element(first2, last2, i);
        cin >> i;
    }

    cout << "\nEnter the position of the element after which to insert the second list: ";
    int pos;
    cin >> pos;

    // Find the element at the specified position
    p = first1;
    for (int i = 1; i < pos && p != NULL; i++) {
        p = p->next;
    }

    // Check if the specified position is valid
    if (p == NULL) {
        cout << "\nError: Position out of range." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Insert the second list after the specified element
    insert_list(first1, last1, p, first2, last2);

    cout << "\nThe updated list: " << endl;
    print_list(first1);
    cout << endl;

    delete_list(first1);
    delete_list(first2);
    cout << endl;
    if(first2->next) cout << "first2 pastaav " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried ChatGPT, but that didn't work really, maybe I don't know how to use it properly :D.
I'll add picture with example: https://prnt.sc/gBCe0WCfHF5q

Comment: you've added `first2` to `first1` so don't need to delete it?

Comment: When you insert the list, `first1` points to the elements of both lists combined. When you delete `first1`, **all** elements are deleted, since your deletion iterates over all `elem`s and deletes them. Subsequently calling delete on `first2` deletes already freed memory, giving you the error.

Comment: Side note: NULL is in C. In C++, `nullptr` is preferred.

Comment: So if element exists in two lists, its address is still the same, so once you delete it in one list, it gets deleted from all, did I understand that right? @AlanBirtles B_Remmelzwaal

Comment: @RaivisLuriņš yes of course. The element exists only _once_. But if two _pointers_ point to an _element_ and you delete the element pointed by the first pointer, the second pointer will point to an inexistent element, hence the problem.

Comment: In modern C++, use smart pointers for **owning** pointers, and use *raw pointers* for non-owning pointers.  That will avoid the problem of having to keep track if a raw pointer is an owning or non-owning pointer.

Comment: *I've tried ChatGPT* -- So you really thought that an AI program would recognize your code and make changes to it?  Seriously? There are millions of programs written in millions of different ways, using millions of different functions, variable names, language used, etc.

Comment: Some day that will be possible, but not yet.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Chatgpt is rather fluent in many languages, english, c++, etc. It will answer almost anything. And it talks to you in such a nice english that you almost miss to realize that the generated code is trash. Its rather dangerous for beginners actually

Comment: I think the people that write the initial program from scratch, see that there is a bug, and really expect ChatGPT to fix the bug for them -- they will be highly disappointed and find out it was a waste of time using ChatGPT.  That time could have been spent on debugging the code using the normal methods of using a debugger.  Now, if you were to ask ChatGPT to write a linked list program in modern C++, **from scratch**, then maybe you would get something of worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments already pointed out, you are inserting the nodes, not the elements, into your first list. This causes the second list to point into the first list.

It looks like this:

```
main::p1 ->  1 -  2 -  3 -  4 -  5  
main::p2 -> 11 - 22 - 33 - 44 - 55
```

after your insertion, it looks like this:

```
main::p1 ->  1 -  2 \                          / 3 -  4 -  5  
main::p2 -> ---------\ 11 - 22 - 33 - 44 - 55 /
```

When you now try to delete both lists, you will get a double deletion, because main still has a reference to `11` via `p2`, even `p1` now "owns" it.

A quick fix would be, when you override the first pointer of the second list with the next pointer of the last element of the second list. This may have the disadvantage, that it does nothing, when the pointer was copied before.

Imagine the following, and you insert the first 5 elements into p1:

```
main::p1 ->  1 -  2 -  3 -  4 -  5  
main::p2 -> 11 - 22 - 33 - 44 - 55 - 66
```

Then it would look like this:

```
main::p1 ->  1 -  2 - 11 - 22 - 33 - 44 - 55 -  3 -  4 -  5  
main::p2 -> 66
```

And you can safely delete both lists.

```
void insert_list(elem*& first1, elem* p, elem*& first2, elem* last2) {
  // Store the next pointer of last2 for later deletion.
  auto last2next = last2->next;
    // Update the next pointer of the last element of the second list to point to NULL
    // last2->next = NULL; // Redundant, must be allways overridden with p->next or first anyway.
    // Assuming you insert after p
    // Insert at the beginning of the list, when p == nullptr
    auto*& begin_pointer = (p == nullptr) ? first1 : p->next;
    last2->next = begin_pointer;
    begin_pointer = first2;
    // override the original first2 pointer with the saved last2.next pointer.
    first2 = last2next;
}
```

===

But to give you general feedback: Your code looks more like C than C++.
First, you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.
(Same applies for `FALSE` -> `false` and `TRUE` `true`). Those makros are all pure C.

Second, unless this is a school or university task, you should avoid raw pointers (`T*`). Instead, use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

In c++ mostly everything is handled via indirect dynamic memory management. This means, that you pass control structures either by value or by `const&`. They keep track of their own internal dynamic memory. As soon they go out of scope, they clear their own allocated resources. This principle is called [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

Using unique_ptr might be a bit complicated, because you can't copy them, but you can std::move them, which basically steals the ownership: `auto new_ptr_owner = std::move(varname_of_old_unique_ptr);`

This forces you, to do memory management correct. And is also as efficient as the use of raw pointers.
If you don't care for efficiency, you could just use shared_ptr. They are copyable, because they count all copies of it. When the count reaches zero, the pointer deletes the own resources.

Third, you might want to define your linked list, to always contain an invalid first element, which is basically your list. It is empty, when your first list element has no next value. This will reduce code overhead, because you are not required to check if p is nullptr, since it will always be a valid element.

Alternatively, write a wrapper class:

```
class LinkedList {
    struct Node {
        int value{};
        std::unique_ptr<Node > next;
        Node* prev {}; // Not required, convenience
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Node> first; // Required
    Node* last;  // Optional, to quickly insert at the end.
    size_t size;    // Optional, convenience.

    public:

    void insert(Node begin_n, Node last_n); // Todo implement
    void emplace_last(int value); // Todo implement
};
```

Note, that each node can only be reached over one smart pointer at the same time. With a `unique_ptr` it won't compile, with a `shared_ptr` you will get a dependency loop (They will keep them alive reciprocally).